# How is a mime player Activex control supposed to retrieve the path for the document?

Tags: c#, com, activex

I'm working on an ActiveX control, and the control is being correctly instantiated based on the Mime Type. I'm trying to understand how to retrieve the path to the file.

[This *very* old (deprecated) KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165072) specifically says:

> In all cases Internet Explorer passes the URL of the file to play to
>   the default player via the `IPropertyBag` interface. That is, when
>   Internet Explorer launches a player, it creates an instance of
>   IPropertyBag and loads the "SRC" property with the URL of the file to
>   play. Then it queries the player for IPersistPropertyBag and sends it
>   the `IPropertyBag` instance through `IPersistPropertyBag::Load`.

I implemented this, but the load method never gets called.

```
    int IPersistPropertyBag.Load(IPropertyBag pIPropertyBag, object pErrorLog)
    {
        object var = null;
        pIPropertyBag.Read("SRC", out var, (IErrorLog)pErrorLog);
        return 0;
    }
```

There's also a [wealth of information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this article talks extensively about using BindToStorage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the `IBindStatusCallback::OnDataAvailable` event. I suspect that this is now the way to go about retrieving the source path for the document, but any confirmation or direction is much appreciated.

One last note: the control DOES implement IObjectSafety, and supports `INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by exposing a [Data Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768183(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#define GUID_PathProperty 0002DE80-0000-0000-C000-000000000046

[id(1), bindable, displaybind, propput, 
    custom(GUID_PathProperty, "application/custom-mime-type")] 
    HRESULT put_Src(BSTR src);
```

Alternatively, I believe if your ActiveX MIME player control implements `IPersistMoniker`, then you could obtain the URL via `IMoniker::GetDisplayName`: [How To Find the URL of an ActiveX Document from Inside the Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178059).

Finally, there may be cases when the data is embedded via [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) scheme and the URL is not available. Your control should be able to handle this, e.g.:

```html
<object src="data:application/custom-mime-type;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
</object>
```

**Updated**, the following is a simple test web page for Adobe PDF ActiveX Control (ProgID `AcroPDF.PDF`, CLSID `{ca8a9780-280d-11cf-a24d-444553540000}`), which is an established Mime Player for PDF.

```html
<body>

<object
  classid="clsid:ca8a9780-280d-11cf-a24d-444553540000" id="pdf1" 
  type="application/pdf"
  data="test.pdf"
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%">

<param name="src" "value"="test.pdf"></param>

</object>

</body>
```

To make it work with a local (`file://`) PDF document, I had to specify both the `data` attribute and the `src` param. When it was served from `http://localhost`, the `data` alone was just enough.

Here is the list of COM/OLE interfaces it implements, obtained with OleView:

[image: AcroPDF.PDF Contol]

The interesting ones: `IMonikerProp` (which may be the answer to your original question), `IDataObject`, `IPersistFile`, `IPersistMoniker`, `IPersistStreamInit`, `IPersistPropertyBag`. I'd implement all of them and see what gets called.

I can't answer the question on how to add a custom `GUID_PathProperty` typelib attribute to the type library generated by RegAsm for a C# project. I'm not even sure this is a hard requirement for a mime player. I'd be interested to know both answers if you managed to find them. Possibly, one option is to develop a wrapper ActiveX control in C++, which would just forward everything to the C# implementation.

Comment: First, thanks for answering. I've tried to implement `IPersistMoniker`, but I never got a breakpoint on any function other than the constructor. [Here is a pastebin with the current code](http://pastebin.com/vWkTNUUL). Any suggestions on why IPersistMoniker::Load() never fires? Also, I added a key for `{0DE86A51-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}` under the `Implemented Categories` registry key for this control's CLSID. I'm not sure if this was necessary or not, and [neither was this person](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2070999/656243). Although it certainly seems like it isn't necessary.

Comment: One other note: I looked around quite a bit, but wasn't sure how to implement Data Path Properties in c#. It feels like I need to do more than simply adding a public property (namely, decorating it attributes that may not even exist in c#.)

Comment: Well, it appears what I want is an [Active Document Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ha0eexy.aspx). MFC makes this REALLY easy via the CDocObjectServer class. At this point, I'd we willing to put up a 500 pt bounty for a C# implementation of that class. Grr.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, an Active Document is required only if you want to show the custom content inside Internet Explorer (or WebBrowser control) *without any adorning HTML* (i.e., when the user navigates to the content URL). It won't work as an `<OBJECT>`. Is this what you need? This is not exactly a MIME player.

Comment: Yes - it's exactly what I need. Specifically, I'll be using a 3rd party PDF render library (PDFView4Net) inside of an ActiveX. I essentially need to replace the Acrobat Reader IE plugin.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.. I was under the impression this was called a mime player, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, then I suggest that you start here: ["ACTIVEDOC Sample: Implements an Active Document Server"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dssbex6h(v=vs.90).aspx). Porting ATL COM code to C# is much easier than MFC, as it's much less coupled.

Comment: Funny that you mentioned that sample app. I actually already had it downloaded, but hadn't opened it yet, since I hadn't yet realized that it was exactly what I needed. Here's the thing: I can get it to behave the way that I want IF I added `EnableFullPage\.pdf` and `Control` reg keys under the CLSID, and then use it's CLSID in  `HKCR\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf`. It doesn't seem to want to open it's open AAA format on it's own.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, search the web for `BrowseInPlace` registry entry, and check how Adobe uses it. This is probably as much as I can help with this question.

Comment: It's been a while, but I finally figured out how to accomplish most of this in C#. MANY of your other answers have been incredibly useful, but I can't upvote more than a couple without risking a serial upvote. It looks like I need MIME player in conjunction with the [interface requirements an Active Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9c54kf.aspx). I'm almost there.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to accept this. It's been a year, and I'm still fine-tuning.