# How to implement EPM(Enhanced protection Mode) compatibility in managed code (c#)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I have a IE BHO written in c# that works on IE 8,9 in both 32, 64 bits. and it also works in IE 10, 11 in 32 bit mode. I have found out from several posts that  I need to make my BHO AppContainerCompatible. So I included this in my registry

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{MyBHOGUID}\Implemented Categories{59fb2056-d625-48d0-a944-1a85b5ab2640}

Also placed my BHO's DLL with in an AppContainer-readable folder(C:\Program Files\MyBHO). But still it is not working.

I also read in here "[Is the 'Implemented Categories' key needed when registering a Managed COM Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070999/is-the-implemented-categories-key-needed-when-registering-a-managed-com-compon)" that the CATID is found in HKCR\Component Catogeries. The GUID for CATID_AppContainerCompatible is not in that location.

and also I am building MyBHO using AnyCPU mode. But when I install it it is shown as only 64 bit in Manage Addons window.

Any help is greatly appriciated

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean when you say it works in 32-bit mode?  Do you mean 32-bit mode on a 64-bit OS or works as a 32-bit process on a 32-bit OS?

Comment: @CodeWhore , It works in 32 bit mode on 64 bit OS

Comment: When you say not working are we to assume that the BHO is not loading at all?  Do you have any logging in the start up of the BHO to indicate it is starting and later failing or just never being invoked by the browser? NOTE: if you add some logging to a file make sure you log to a directory that a low integrity process and log to (like /users/<username>/AppData/LocalLow) Have you tried debugging it via visual studio?  Also, how are you installing it? Continued in next comment...

Comment: Have you tried RegAsm /codebase myBHO.dll?  This should set up all of the registry keys.  Note that there is both a 32-bit and 64-bit RegAsm (/windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727 and ,,,/Framework64/v2.0.50727).  Running these on a x64 machine should create all of the necessary registry keys for 32/64 bit runtimes -- then you can search for your DLL name and GUID to see what keys you may be missing. I suspect that perhaps your install method is only registering your BHO as 32-bit in the Wow6432 part of the registry but I am speculating because I don't know exactly what you have done